# How to evaluate $\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy} \, dy \, dx$ to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, riemann-zeta

I've read somewhere on this site that if you consider:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy} \,dy\,dx$$

Then using the power series, we have this is equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ which I decided to try and was able to show.

Apparently we can show this is equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, and using what little I know about double integrals from a few khan academy videos (I haven't taken multivariable  calculus yet), I tried to evaluate this double integral by techniques of single variable calculus $u=xy$..and I got this:

$$-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln (1-x)}{x}dx$$

The usual way I would evaluate this is with a Taylor series, but that just that just leads us in circles.

So I want to know how can I evaluate this, so we can prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: Why don't you simply compute $f(x) := \int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{1-xy}dy$ and then $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ ?

Comment: That's what I did, but that doesn't help what I'm trying to get at. @paf

Comment: Do you want to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$?

Comment: Yes, and by this method because it seems much easier than everything else I have seen. @BehrouzMaleki

Comment: Fourier series is faster and easier.

Comment: I haven't learned about that yet @BehrouzMaleki

Comment: Actually, can you please post an answer anyways I might be able to understand. @BehrouzMaleki

Comment: I like to help you but it leads to OP.

Comment: Look at this:   http://math.cmu.edu/~bwsulliv/basel-problem.pdf

Comment: Really great document, thank you :)

Comment: Yes thanks @ChristianBlatter . It would be a nice answer, so that this question has a legitimate "answer".

Comment: Have a look at the first part of my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/617710/44121

Comment: This is more famously known as the Basel Problem, if you are interested in getting a wider view.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here, we present an approach the relies on integration methodologies only, including transformation of coordinates.  To that end we proceed.

We can transform coordinates by setting $x=s+t$ and $y=s-t$.  Then, $dx\,dy\to 2\,ds\,dt$ and the transformed integral domain is the square-shaped region with vertices in the $s-t$ plane at $(0,0)$, $(1/2,1/2)$, $(1/2,-1/2)$, and $(1,0)$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy&=\int_0^{1/2}\int_{-s}^{s}\frac{2}{(1-s^2)+t^2}\,dt\,ds+\int_{1/2}^{1}\int_{s-1}^{1-s}\frac{2}{(1-s^2)+t^2}\,dt\,ds\\\\
&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\right)\,ds\\\\&+\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-s}{1+s}}\right)\,ds\\\\
&=4\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\arcsin(s)}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\,ds+4\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\arccos(s)}{2\sqrt{1-s^2}}\,ds\\\\
&=2\arcsin^2(1/2)+\arccos^2(1/2)\\\\
&=2\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^2\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Substitution is kind of weird in two variables. I guess I'll have to dig deeper in it. And $\arctan(\frac{s}{\sqrt{1-s^2}})$ can be simplified by setting it equal to $\theta$, taking the tangent of both sides, and considering the right triangle with opposite $s$ and adjacent $\sqrt{1-s^2}$ if I remember right, correct? And thanks for your answer which is a little bit different than Christian Blatters comment.

Comment: Integration under coordinate transformation requires calculation of the Jacobian.  And yes, your observation is consistent with $\arctan(s/\sqrt{1-s^2}=\arcsin(s)$ and $\arctan(\sqrt{(1-s)/(1+s)}=\frac12 \arccos(s)$.  I had not read the comment from Christian Blatters before posting this.  But I had a brief look and think it is a really solid reference!  -Mark

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: I believe you have a mistype in line where you you first go from double integrals to single @Dr.MV .

Comment: I see the same integral twice. @Dr.MV

Comment: But what about $\arctan (\sqrt{\frac{1-s}{1+s}})$ you never right than anywhere in your answer. @Dr.MV

Comment: Ahmed, good catch on the typo. Thank you.  I've edited.  I guess this highlights the danger of cutting and pasting.  ;-))

Comment: In the upper right integral the upper $s$ limit ($2$) and the numerator of the integrand ($1$) may have been switched.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, indeed.  I've edited.  Thank you for the catch.  -Mark

Comment: Would the down voter care to comment?

Comment: (+1) - but I think you have mini typos in the third double  integral of the first line... The $2$ in the upper $s$ limit should be $1$?  And you're missing the $2$ of the Jacobian transformation (probably it migrated to the limit)?

Comment: @peterag Great catch!  Much appreciated.  I've edited accordingly.  -Mark