# $s=1+\frac{1}{2^{2}}+\frac{1}{3^{2}}+\frac{1}{4^{2}}+\frac{1}{5^{2}}+..$ then,is $ S=6$ or $S=8$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $$S=1+\frac{1}{2^{2}}+\frac{1}{3^{2}}+\frac{1}{4^{2}}+\frac{1}{5^{2}}+..$$
>
> a)$S=6$
>
> b)$S=8$
>
> c) Series does not converge
>
> d) None of the above

Comment: If you want proofs, there are a bunch [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2). And I mean proofS.

Answer (score 4):

Note that since $k>k-1$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^2}&< 1+\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k(k-1)}\\\\
&=1+\sum_{k=2}^n \left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac1k\right)\\\\
&=2-\frac{1}{n}
\end{align}$$

Hence the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^2}$ converges and is bounded above by $2$.

The answer is d) None of the above.

> In [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884418/how-to-evaluate-int-01-int-01-frac11-xy-dy-dx-to-prove-sum-n/1885211#1885211), I evaluated the series in closed form using straightforward integration including transformation of coordinates.  The result is of course $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is d): The sum is $\pi^2/6$ if I recall correctly.

Comment: You recall [correctly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1+%2F+n%5E2), but the answer is useless without any justification or even a hint thereof.