# Evaluating Definite Integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{e^x-1}dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am looking for alternative ways to solve the Basel problem using only real analysis and without using the infinite product for sine. I have transformed the summation into the given integral below. It looks like a deceivingly simply integral to evaluate, but none of the websites that I have plugged it into have been able to solve it. One of them even claimed that it was a divergent integral. Through numerical integration I have verified that the integral is equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. I am hoping that someone will be able to prove the integral is equal to its known closed form. For the purposes of this proof, start with the integral, and do not revert to the initial summation.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \int_0^\infty \frac x {e^x-1} \, dx = \frac{\pi^2} 6$$

#### $$\text{Transform Explanation:}$$

$$a(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2}$$
$$a(0)=0 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space a(1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^2}$$
$$a(1)=\int_0^1{a'(x)dx}$$
$$a'(x)=\frac{1}{x}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{n}}}$$
$$b(x)={\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{n}}} \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space a'(x)=\frac{b(x)}{x}$$
$$b(0)=0 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space b(x)=\int_0^x{b'(t)dt}$$
$$b'(x)={\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n}}=\frac{1}{1-x} \space\space\space\space\space For \space\space -1<x<1$$
$$b(x)=\int_0^x{\frac{dt}{1-t}}=-\ln|1-x|$$
$$a'(x)=\frac{-\ln|1-x|}{x}$$
$$a(1)=\int_0^1{\frac{-\ln|1-x|}{x}dx}=\int_0^1 \frac{-\ln(1-x)} x \, dx$$
$u=-\ln(1-x) \space\space\space\space -u=\ln(1-x) \space\space\space\space e^{-u} = 1-x \space\space\space\space x=1-e^{-u} \space\space\space\space dx=e^{-u} \, du$
$u(x)=-\ln(1-x) \space\space\space\space u(0^+)=0 \space\space\space\space u(1^-)=\infty$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{-\ln(1-x)}{x} \, dx =\int_0^\infty \frac{ue^{-u}}{1-e^{-u}} \, du$$
$$a(1)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{e^x-1}\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^2}$$
Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is your question ? $n^{-2} = n^{-2} \int_0^\infty x e^{-x}dx = \int_0^\infty y e^{-ny}dy$ so that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \int_0^\infty y e^{-ny}dy=\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_0^\infty y\frac{1-e^{-Ny}}{e^y-1}dy=\int_0^\infty \frac{y}{e^y-1}dy$$

Comment: The question is to prove that the given integral equals pi^2/6

Comment: I don't think you can compute it from $\int_0^\infty \frac{y}{e^y-1}dy$.  There are many proofs of $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#A_rigorous_proof_using_Fourier_series

Comment: @reuns See below for solutions.  :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that by enforcing the substitution $x\to -\log(1-x)$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-1}\,dx&=-\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Then, in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884418/how-to-evaluate-int-01-int-01-frac11-xy-dy-dx-to-prove-sum-n/1885211#1885211), I used the transformation $x=s+t$ and $y=s-t$ to directly evaluate the transformed integral

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy&=\int_0^{1/2}\int_{-s}^{s}\frac{2}{(1-s^2)+t^2}\,dt\,ds+\int_{1/2}^{1}\int_{s-1}^{1-s}\frac{2}{(1-s^2)+t^2}\,dt\,ds\\\\
&=2\frac{\pi^2}{6^2}+\frac{\pi^2}{9}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With [Abel-Plana Formula ("$\ds{\mathsf{\underline{finite\ version}}}$")](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.E2) :

\begin{align}
\sum_{x = 0}^{n}x & = \int_{0}^{n}x\,\dd x + {1 \over 2}\,0 + {1 \over 2}\,n -
2\,\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ic x \over \expo{2\pi x} - 1}\,\dd x + {B_{2} \over 2}
\end{align}

> $\ds{B_{s}}$ is a [Bernoulli Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). Note that
>   $\ds{B_{2} = {1 \over 6}}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
{n\pars{n + 1} \over 2} & = {n^{2} \over 2} + {n \over 2} -
2\,{1 \over \pars{2\pi}^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x + {1 \over 12}
\\[5mm]
\implies &
\bbx{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x = 
{1 \over 2}\,\pars{2\pi}^{2}\,{1 \over 12} = {\pi^{2} \over 6}}
\end{align}

Comment: Ah, that's a nifty one.  +1

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks. Playing with powers yield finite terms as the above $B_{2}/2$.

Comment: Felix, the Abel-Plana formula is based on complex analysis.  ;-)