# Improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{e^{x}-1} \ dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, riemann-zeta

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{e^{x}-1}\ dx$$
>   Is there a way to evaluate this integral without using the zeta function?

Comment: In some sense. You don't need to mention $\zeta(s)$ nor $\zeta(2)$, but all the known proofs are explained in the [big lists](https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/cillerue/Curso/zeta2.pdf) for $\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**By Means of Complex Analysis**

We prove the general formula

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin(ax)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\,dx = \frac{1}{4}\coth\left(\frac{a}{2} \right)-\frac{1}{2a}$$

Which can be used to generate many values by differentiation with respect to $a$
By integrating the following function

$$f(z) = \frac{e^{iaz}}{e^{2\pi z}-1}$$

The function is analytic in and on the contour, indented at the poles of the function

[image]

Hence by the residue theorem

$$\int_{\gamma_{\epsilon_2}}f(z)\,dz+\int^R_{\epsilon_2}f(x)\,dx+\int^{R+i}_{R}f(x)\,dx\\+\int_{R+i}^{i+\epsilon_2}f(x)\,dx+\int_{\gamma_{\epsilon_1}}f(z)\,dz-\int^{i-i\epsilon_1}_{i\epsilon_2}f(x)\,dx=0$$

Let us first look at with $ R \to \infty $

\begin{align}\left|\int_{R}^{R+i} \frac{e^{iax}}{e^{2\pi x}-1} \,dx\right| &=\left|iR\int^1_0\frac{e^{ia(R+ixR)}}{e^{2\pi (R+ixR)}-1} \,dx\right| \\&\leq R\int^1_0\frac{|e^{ia(R+ixR)}|}{|e^{2\pi (R+ixR)}-1|} \,dx
\\&\leq \frac{R}{|e^{2\pi R}-1|} \int^1_0 e^{-axR} \,dx
\\&= \frac{1}{a|e^{2\pi R}-1|} (1-e^{-aR}) \sim_{\infty} 0\end{align}

The next integral can be reduced to
\begin{align}
\int^{i(1-\epsilon_1)}_{i\epsilon_2}\frac{e^{iax}}{e^{2\pi x}-1} \,dx &= i \int^{(1-\epsilon_1)}_{\epsilon_2}\frac{e^{-ax}}{e^{2\pi i x}-1} \,dx \\&= \frac{1}{2}\int^{(1-\epsilon_1)}_{\epsilon_2}\frac{e^{-ax}}{\sin(\pi x) e^{i\pi x}} \,dx
\\ &= \frac{1}{2}\int^{(1-\epsilon_1)}_{\epsilon_2}\frac{e^{-ax}}{\sin(\pi x) e^{i\pi x}} \,dx
\\ &= \frac{1}{2}\int^{(1-\epsilon_1)}_{\epsilon_2}\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x) }e^{-ax} \,dx-\frac{i}{2}\int^{(1-\epsilon_1)}_{\epsilon_2}e^{-ax} \,dx\end{align}

Since the first integral diverges when $ \epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \to 0 $

$$ PV\int^{i}_{0}\frac{e^{iax}}{e^{2\pi x}-1} \,dx =PV \int^{1}_{0}\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{2\sin(\pi x) }e^{-ax} \,dx-i\frac{1-e^{-a}}{2a} $$

The remaining integrals can be evaluated using residues
$$\lim_{\epsilon_2 \to 0} \int_{\gamma_{\epsilon_2}}f(z)\,dz = -\frac{\pi i}{2}\mathrm{Res}(f,0)= -\frac{i}{4}$$

$$\lim_{\epsilon_1 \to 0} \int_{\gamma_{\epsilon_1}}f(z)\,dz = -\frac{\pi\,i}{2}\mathrm{Res}(f,i)= -\frac{i}{4}e^{-a}$$

By combining the results together

$$PV\int^\infty_{0}\frac{e^{iax}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\,dx -PV\int^\infty_{0}\frac{e^{ia(x+i)}}{e^{2\pi (x+i)}-1}\,dx \\-PV \int^{1}_{0}\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{2\sin(\pi x) }e^{-ax} \,dx+i\frac{1-e^{-a}}{2a} = i\frac{e^{-a}+1}{4}$$

Which reduces to

$$(1-e^{-a})PV\int^\infty_{0}\frac{e^{iax}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\,dx -PV \int^{1}_{0}\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{2\sin(\pi x) }e^{-ax} \,dx = i\frac{e^{-a}+1}{4}-i\frac{1-e^{-a}}{2a}$$

By equating the real part

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin(ax)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\,dx = \frac{1}{4}\coth\left(\frac{a}{2} \right)-\frac{1}{2a}$$

Now by differentiation and letting $a \to 0 $

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{x}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\,dx = \frac{1}{24}$$

Then the result follows by $y = 2\pi x$.

Comment: I would mention with $f(z) = \frac{z^{-2}}{e^{z}-1}-\frac{1}{12 z}$ then $$\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z| = 2\pi (N +1/2)} f(z) dz= \sum_{n= -N,n \ne 0}^N Res(f(z),2\pi n) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2} \int_0^\infty x \frac{1-e^{-Nx}}{e^x-1}dx$$ Letting $N \to \infty$ yields the desired result.

Comment: :-) Nicely done!

Comment: +1 ... It's always great to see contour integration used to solve real analysis problems.

Comment: @reuns what isthe motivation of the choice of the function?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai What do you mean ? $ \frac{2i \pi z^{-2}}{e^{2i \pi z}-1} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{z^2(z-n)}$. And I meant $f(z) =  \frac{2i \pi z^{-2}}{e^{2i \pi z}-1} + \frac{1}{12 z}$ or something like that

Comment: @reuns,nice approach but why using $1/(12 z)$ ?

Comment: It is $\frac{-Res(f,0)}{z} = \frac{-B_3/3!}{z}$ the Bernouilli number, and the same argument applied to $\frac{z^{-2k}}{e^z-1}+\frac{B_{2k+1}/(2k+1)!}{z}$ works for evaluating $\zeta(2k)$ and $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2k-1}}{e^x-1}dx$

Comment: @reuns,makes sense. Thanks for the approach.

Answer (score 9):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**

We can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-1}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty \frac{xe^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty xe^{-(n+1)x}\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}$$

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**

Enforcing the substitution $x=-\log(1-u)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-1}\,dx&=-\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)}{u}\,du\\\\
&=\text{Li}_2(1)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}$$

---

**METHODOLOGY $3$:**

If one doesn't like either of the first two methodologies, then one can proceed as follows.  Begin as in Methodology $2$ and enforce the substitution $x=-\log(1-u)$.

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-1}\,dx&=-\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)}{u}\,du\\\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Then, in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884418/how-to-evaluate-int-01-int-01-frac11-xy-dy-dx-to-prove-sum-n/1885211#1885211), I evaluated the double integral in $(1)$ by using the transformation $x=s+t$ and $y=s-t$.  This facilitates using real analysis only, and without appealing to special functions to arrive at

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Gosh darn it, you took all the answers!  Hmph... +1

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Well, thank you!  I'm sure that there is another way.  I actually prefer the third methodology here since it circumvents appeal to special functions or a priori knowledge that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.  Interestingly, the methodology was introduced in 1983 by Tom Apostle.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to find a method that avoided special functions.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, not all of them ;).

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{ if } L(f) = F(s) \implies \int_0^{\infty} \frac f{e^t-1}dt = \sum_{s\ge1} F(s)$$
$$L(t) =\frac 1{s^2}\implies\int_0^{\infty} \frac t{e^t-1}dt = \sum_{s\ge1}\frac 1{s^2}  = \zeta(2) $$